# Change "Read more" text in Featured Categories module

Tags: translation

How do I change the "read more" text in the [Featured Categories module](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/featured-categories)?

So I've experienced in the past, that I really just have to change the content language to my local language (danish) for it to go from "read more" to "Læs mere" but it isn't happening for this extension.

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or the extension just isn't compatible. But just in case I want to change it completely to something custom, is the best option to make an alternative edit of the module?

PS. just by habit, I setup my Joomla sites to English, but I usually have to change at least the content to Danish, sometimes also the admin as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module in question uses language files, but only comes with English (en-GB) language. You have a couple of ways to translate the module:

1. **Use language overrides**
   In your Joomla admin area, go to **Extensions** -> **Language(s)**, and press the <kbd>New</kbd> button. 
   [image: Language overrides]
   Make sure the language is set to Danish. You probably want to override one or more of the following constants:

   > MOD_FEATCATS_READ_MORE="Read more " 
   >   MOD_FEATCATS_READ_MORE_TITLE="Read
   >   More" MOD_FEATCATS_REGISTER_TO_READ_MORE="Register to read more"

   Save and close, and you're done. More on language overrides can be [found here](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Language_Overrides_in_Joomla).
2. **Create a Danish language file**
   In case you want to translate most of the module, you can create your own language file.
   Copy the following files from `ROOT\languages\en-GB\` to `ROOT\languages\da-DK\` and rename them as indicated:
     `en-GB.mod_featcats.sys.ini` rename to `da-DK.mod_featcats.sys.ini`
     `en-GB.mod_featcats.ini` rename to `da-DK.mod_featcats.ini`

   Now simply go through the files and translate the text inside double quotes.
3. **Use a translation component**
   There are some Joomla components that helps you handle extension translation, take a look at the [Joomla Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/languages/language-edition/freestyle-translation-manager).

Comment: @Dsan, if you choose option 2, and feel like helping, you might want to consider sending the translation to the extension developer in case he wants to add it to future releases.